# How to get IMDb IDs of all films in a list page on Wikipedia?

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata, wikidata-api

I want to get the IMDb ID of all films in a list page on Wikipedia, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neo-noir_films

I've tried making a query like this: (instance of: film, genre: neo-noir)

```
SELECT ?film ?filmLabel ?IMDb_ID WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424;
    wdt:P136 wd:Q2421031.
  OPTIONAL { ?film wdt:P345 ?IMDb_ID. }
}
```

but the list it returned is not the same as that list page. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you expand on what the difference is? Are there some films missing from Wikidata that are on the wikipedia list?
If so which?
You might want to try adding `/wdt:P279*` after `wdt:P31` and `wdt:P136`. This will return works that are classified as some subclass of films with genres that are a subclass of neo-noir.
It adds 24 results to what your query showed.

Comment: @ValerioCocchi Thanks. I've tried your solution, it still doesn't give the complete list of movies. There are 775 titles in that wiki page. An example not in the results is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrath_of_Man

Comment: It looks like this specific film's genre is listed as 'action film' instead of 'neo-noir'.
I suppose that Wikidata and Wikipedia may not always be in sync.

Comment: @privil You can find the info missing in wikidata using [the petscan query](https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?psid=21312169) and fix the wikidata.